# CSS: What does question mark means in a square?

Tags: css, sass

I have found a question mark in a square in css code. It belongs to a class of a font item. The CSS is generated from SCSS.

What does the question mark in the square mean? My search with Startpage didn't provide any explanation. Who can help?

[image]

The SCSS code:

[image]

Comment: Fair point for the second code. But how should I post the first code? I have no idea how to get a question mark into a square.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly is a specific icon of the font.
Because your font (currently in use - not the one used in css/scss) does not support this given character, it can not be displayed.

**Update**
It means your current font (to view the characters) does not support this Character.

Fonts using something like this:

[image: font table]

Each character has his own address to identify it. And this square is outside your supported characters of your IDE/Editor.

What your using is an address (sometimes you see `\E1234`) to the icon `search` from FontAwesome.

Comment: do you mean, that the browser font doesn't fit the css/scss font? by the way: The font icon is correctly shown on the webside.

Answer (score 0):

This shows when the interpreter failed to convert. What was the SASS content for the same?